# OKTA - OAuthError: Illegal value for redirect_uri parameter

Tags: oauth-2.0, okta, okta-api

I am working in my Developer Account in OKTA.

I am trying to get a Very Simple SPA App to obtain a JWT From OKTA.

1. I login with **authClient.signIn({})** and that returns a transaction.sessionToken/
2. With that Session Token I should be able to call **authClient.token.getWithoutPrompt({})** but I can never reach that code.

I get the following error: OAuthError: Illegal value for redirect_uri parameter.

How do I get beyond this OAuth Error so I can finally get back a JWT. I have tried examples on OKTA GIT but cannot get anything to work.

```
function getJWT()
{
  var orgUrl = 'https://MYXXXXXXX.oktapreview.com'; 
  var keyID = "MY CLIENT ID";

  var user = "MYUSER ID";
  var pwd =  "MY PASWORD"

  var appScope = ['openid', 'email', 'profile', 'phone', 'groups'];  

  var authClient = new OktaAuth({url: orgUrl, clientId: keyID,});

  $('#tokendiv').html('');

  authClient.signIn({
          username: user,
          password: pwd,
          redirectUri:  "http://localhost:5656/test.html"  //THIS IS SETUP IN MY OKTA ID
        })
        .then(function(transaction) {
          if (transaction.status === 'SUCCESS') {
            authClient.session.setCookieAndRedirect(transaction.sessionToken); // Sets a cookie on redirect
            console.log(transaction.sessionToken);
            $('#tokendiv').append('<h4>Session Token</h4>' + transaction.sessionToken);

            /// THIS IS NEVER REACHED, I Always Get OAuthError: Illegal value for redirect_uri parameter.
            authClient.token.getWithoutPrompt({     
              responseType: 'id_token', // or array of types            
              scopes: appScope,
              sessionToken: transaction.sessionToken
            })
              .then(function(res) {
                console.log("JWT: " + jwt);
                $('#tokendiv').append('<h4>JWT</h4>' + res.idToken);
              })
              .fail(function(err) {
                console.log("ERROR " + err);
                $('#tokendiv').append('<h4>Error</h4>' + err);
              })                        

          } else {
            throw 'We cannot handle the ' + transaction.status + ' status';
          }
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: I found that if I removed authClient.token.getWithoutPrompt({ }) I no longer get the error, but I need that method to get the JWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your `redirectUri` is included in the approved **Redirect URIs** in your [Okta Developer organization](http://developer.okta.com/), you should not be receiving that error.

Below I was able to successfully return an `id_token` running on `localhost:5656`.

```
<!-- index.html -->

<html>
    <body>
        <button onClick="getJWT()">Button</button>
        <div id="tokendiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    function getJWT(){
        var orgUrl = 'https://{{org}}.oktapreview.com'; 
        var keyID = "{{clientId}}";

        var user = "{{user}}";
        var pwd =  "{{password}}"

        var appScope = ['openid', 'email', 'profile', 'phone', 'groups'];  

        var authClient = new OktaAuth(
            {
                url: orgUrl,
                clientId: keyID,
                redirectUri: "http://localhost:5656/index.html"
            });

        $('#tokendiv').html('');

        authClient.signIn({
                username: user,
                password: pwd,
        })
        .then(function(transaction) {
            if (transaction.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                authClient.token.getWithoutPrompt({     
                    responseType: 'id_token', // or array of types            
                    scopes: appScope,
                    sessionToken: transaction.sessionToken
                })
                .then(function(res) {
                    $('#tokendiv').append('<h4>JWT</h4>' + res.idToken);
                    console.log("JWT: " + JSON.stringify(res));
                })
                .fail(function(err) { /* err */ })                        
            } else { /* throw error */ }
        })
        .fail(function(err) { /* err */ });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I mentioned.  redirectUri:  "http://localhost:5656/test.html"  //This is setup in my OKTA

Comment: Just wanted to verify. OktaAuth is sending the current browser url, not the redirectUri specified in the configuration object. I've updated my answer to show how to set the redirect.

Comment: Your update showed me the issue. I had redirectUri under the authClient.signIn but (as you showed) it should have been under var authClient = new OktaAuth. THANK YOU!